# Tags that I am in the Top 5 answerers

Tags: discussion, tags, data-explorer, top-users

While reading the [ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis) tag info, I accidentally discover that I am listed in the 5 Top Answerers.

[image]

**Question**

Is there a way to know what are the tags that I am listed in the Top 5 Answerers? Also how can I list these (tags + positions) in the *About me* section?

Comment: I find your choice of colour disturbing.

Comment: @AndrasDeak what's choice of colour?

Comment: The hand-drawn __blue__ circle, of course >:(

Comment: @AndrasDeak it was made by  Windows snipping tool :)

Comment: @Hadi You can click the Pen drop down and select *"Red Pen"*.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek the hero we need

Answer (score 109, accepted):

With the use of [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (short for The Stack Exchange Data Explorer, [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)) and some SQL fu the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/685751/tags-that-i-am-in-the-top-5-answeres?pos=10&UserId=7031230) gives you roughly what you're looking for:

```sql
-- userid: User Id "The id in the url of your Stack Oveflow user profile"
-- pos: Top position "What is the position you're interested in"

-- create a temp table to hold only the tagid's for the OP
-- this should reduce from 80,000 rows to join to way less.
create table #tags(id integer primary key
                  , tagname nvarchar(35)
                  )
                  
insert into #tags
select distinct 
       t.id
     , t.tagname
from tags t
inner join posttags pt on pt.tagid = t.id
inner join posts p on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
where p.owneruserid = ##userid## 


;with top_answerers as (
select a.owneruserid
     , t.tagname 
     , sum(a.score) [tag score]
     , rank() over(partition by t.tagname order by sum(a.score) desc ) as pos
from posts a
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = a.parentid
inner join #tags t on t.id = pt.tagid -- join on the tags temp table
where a.posttypeid = 2 -- answer
and a.owneruserid is not null 
group by a.owneruserid
       , t.tagname
)

select tagname
     , pos
     , owneruserid as [User Link]
     , [tag score]
from top_answerers
where  owneruserid = ##userid?7031230##
and pos <= ##pos?10##
order by pos desc
```

You need to provide your user id (found in the url of [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current)) and a top position, that indicates if you want to see the tags where you are in the top 5, the top 10 or top 100.

Above query does the heavy lifting in the CTE top_answerers by joining the answers in the posts table with the questions in the posts table and joining that via posttags to the tags table. The result is then grouped by user and tagname so we can get the sum of the answer score. By partitioning over tagname and ordering by the sum of scores we get all users rank for that tag.
The main query only needs to limit the results to the user we're interested in and up to which position to include in the final result.

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday so the result of the query might not reflect your current rank.

When run today this is the result:

[image: A resultset for user Hadi, showing tag ssis-2008 for them as position 8]

Unfortunately you can't have this automatically update in your profile as the about me box doesn't allow for running scripts. At best you could host an image on a server you control and then write some parsing code to update the image once a week on your server. I leave that for the reader to implement.

Comment: Thanks for writing this script. It was actually quiet interesting to see what results I go for my username. Apparently I am one of the top answers for the [`bungeecord`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bungeecord/topusers) tag, when I've never even heard of bungeecord. It seems like I once [answered a java questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31105224/4660897) that had extra tags. Now I'm wondering if those extra tags should be removed.

Comment: @TotZam Glad this query gives you all kind of insights and starting points to improve posts. Enjoy!

Comment: I tried to run this for me using the preset value of 10 for "top position", but I got some kind of fatal error. I guess my awesomeness caused an overflow. So I dropped the value down to 5, and promptly learned that I am the #1 answerer for the [tag:application-name] tag. :-/

Comment: I totally confirm your awesomeness @CodyGray although I'm a bit disappointed you're not a gold badge holder in said tag ...

Comment: @rene Smaller tags get way less attention, views and votes, making it many times almost impossible to get a gold badge. I actually think this is a flaw in the gold badge privilege system, since you can have a group of users who are experts in certain tags, yet have no one who has the ability to dupe close obviously duplicate questions. I've spent some times in some smaller tags, and I'm lucky if I even get 1 vote per post, since the posts have very low traffic and are more often than not asked by new users.

Comment: I'm in the top-10 for... [QVector3d] and [jQuery-nestable] (scores of 0 and 2, respectively). Go me. Also neat query. I love seeing SEDE usage, even if my SQL is not...strong enough to write my own queries (I only know enough SQL to be dangerous).

Comment: @Draco18s did you give the [tutorial](http://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) a try?

Comment: @rene I haven't :) But I don't have a need either. I don't have any burning statistics I want to know, I just see other people posting queries and go "oh neat, I wonder what that query returns for me." Usually comes up in a Code Golf situation ("write short code that does X query on Y user(s)"). The SQL quip is just me being a smartass. ;)

Comment: Awesome burnination target query you've got there, rene ;)

Comment: That's disappointing - the only tag I'm in the top ten for is [tag:ora-00917] -
there's a whole bunch of these `ora-xxxxx` tags for Oracle errors that may or may not be burninateable.

Comment: Just ran this query on my Worldbuilding profile. In order of increasing rank, [Chemistry], [Data Storage], and [*lava.*] That's right, I'm the #2 top answerer on [lava] with a score of 22. I'm also #19 for [blood]. I'm on a watch list now, for sure.

Comment: I didn't intent to write queries that give you the shivers @Draco18s ...

Comment: @rene Actually, the blood one should be higher because [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/80301/solid-material-made-from-human-blood) isn't tagged with [blood] and my answer is top, at +55. :worry: (So I'm not really surprised :P )

Comment: Any way to speed up this query?  It used to work but now I get "Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation..." maybe the dump has too much data now?

Comment: @wim what value for `pos` did you try and did you try for your account? I'll see in the weekend if I can apply a tweak.

Comment: I removed one extra join, maybe it becomes a bit better now ... still isn't a wonder of performance  ...

Comment: I had pos 10.  Still very slow but at least works now, thanks  :)   I think the query should also filter out crap tags that have, say, less than 5 posts associated with them, and add a column for the number of posts that user has in that tag.

Comment: @wim yeah, I'm not sure if that is going to cut it. I didn't yet look at the execution plan. Maybe I turn to dba.se or codereview.se to see if others know ways to improve it.

Comment: @wim the query is updated and now runs much better, taking much less time. With Position 10 I do get results for your userid